# Finite sums of infinite value

Tags: sequences-and-series, infinity

If a sum of a finte number of terms is infinite, does that imply that at least one term in the finite sum is also infinite?

Comment: Yeah, because if the terms were all finite, their finite sum would be finite.  This is the contrapositive of your statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $A = a_{1} + \cdots + a_{n}$. If $a_{1} , \ldots , a_{n}$ are all finite, define
$$
\alpha = \max(|a_{1}| , \ldots , |a_{n}|).
$$
Then, we have that
$$
|A| = |a_{1} + \cdots + a_{n}| \leq |a_{1}| + \cdots + |a_{n}| \leq n \alpha,
$$
so that $A$ is also finite.